# Trouble in adding alias in bash_profile

Tags: bash, git

```
for branch in `git branch -r | grep -v HEAD`;do echo -e `git show --format="%ci %cr" $branch | head -n 1` \\t$branch; done | sort -r
```

I want to add the codes above.

I add in ~/.bash_profile since I do not have ~/.bashrc

```
alias latest="for branch in `git branch -r | grep -v HEAD`;do echo -e `git show --format="%ci %cr" $branch | head -n 1` \\t$branch; done | sort -r"
```

When I use it.

```
latest
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `origin/add_material_design_buttons'
```

Expected:

```
for branch in `git branch -r | grep -v HEAD`;do echo -e `git show --format="%ci %cr" $branch | head -n 1` \\t$branch; done | sort -r
2020-03-10 14:38:39 +0000 15 hours ago  origin/develop
2020-02-25 12:54:43 -0600 2 weeks ago   origin/XXXX1
2020-02-19 15:37:03 -0600 3 weeks ago   origin/XXXX2
```

**Updated:**

I comment the wrong one and add the answer,

```
alias latest="for branch in `git branch -r | grep -v HEAD`;do echo -e `git show --format="%ci %cr" $branch | head -n 1` \\t$branch; done | sort -r"
```

and `source ~/.bash_profile`, and then `latest`

it still shows wrong, but could print the branch when I 'source ~/.bash_profile'.

```
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:foundation_android zgong$ latest
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `origin/F11277-MobileFoundation_Analytics_module'
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:foundation_android zgong$ source ~/.bash_profile
-bash: /Users/zgong/.bash_profile: line 19: syntax error near unexpected token `origin/F11277-MobileFoundation_Analytics_module'
-bash: /Users/zgong/.bash_profile: line 19: `for branch in   origin/AddLoggerModule
  origin/F11277-MobileFoundation_Analytics_module
  origin/F12172-MobileFoundation-ProfilingService
  ...
  origin/upgradeMissingKotlinVersion
  origin/zakavila/android_build_scripts_test;do echo -e 2020-03-10 14:38:39 +0000 2 days ago \t; done | sort -r '
```

When I open a new terminal, and type 'latest' in another repo, it works.

Why I need to close the existing iTerm terminal and must open a new one to make it work?

Comment: Use a function instead of an alias.

Comment: @FrancisBacon : Since you are using double-quotes for defining _latest_, `$branch` is expanded at the time where the alias is defined, not when it is executed. The same applies to the expansion of your `git` command.

Comment: See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for the correct way to iterate over the output of a command.

Comment: @user1934428  Could you give me a code which is matching my expectation? Or you are saying it could be implemented?

Comment: @chepner Could you give me a code which is matching my expectation? Or you are saying it could be implemented?

Comment: @FrancisBacon: As _Jetchisel_ said, use a function. This saves you already the need to wrap your complex command between quotes, and makes quoting errors less likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try a function instead.

```
latest(){ for branch in `git branch -r | grep -v HEAD`;do echo -e `git show --format="%ci %cr" $branch | head -n 1` \\t$branch; done | sort -r; }
```

Run

```
latest
```

- Alias don't take arguments.

Comment: It does not work correctly, I will update the result.

Comment: Sorry, when I open a new terminal, and type 'tatest' in another repo, it works.

Before I comment the wrong one and add your answer, and source ~/.bash_profile, it still shows wrong, but could print the branch when I 'source ~/.bash_profile'. Do you know why?

Comment: @Jetchisel : Maybe for easier reading and better style, you could split the function into several lines, and also replace the deprecated backquote expression by `$(....)`.

Comment: @user1934428, yes it is always advised to use  `$( )` instead of  backticks.

Comment: @FrancisBacon, do you have an alias name latest?

Comment: @Jetchisel I had before, but I commented it out, and source the bash file to make it effective. Why do you ask it?

Answer (score -1):

Rewrite it like this

```
alias latest='for branch in $(git branch -r | grep -v HEAD); do printf "$(git show --format="%ci %cr" $branch | head -n 1)\t$branch\n"; done | sort -r'
```